# Internal Server Error when POSTing. Spring-boot

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, post, web

I'm issuing a POST using Postman with the payload:

```
{
"id" : "6",
"type" : "BUY",
"numOfShares" : "5000",
"pricePerShare" : "45.23",
"ticker" : "XYZ",
"commission" : "4.95",
"comments" : "Mgmt Change"
}
```

The Logic that handles my POST in REST Controller is:

```
@PostMapping("/transactions")
public Transaction addTransaction(@PathVariable Map<String, String> newTransaction){
    int transID = Integer.parseInt(newTransaction.get("id"));
    TransactionType transType;
    if(newTransaction.get("type").toUpperCase().equals("BUY")){
        transType = TransactionType.BUY;
    }else if(newTransaction.get("type").toUpperCase().equals("SELL")){
        transType = TransactionType.SELL;
    }else{
        transType = null;
    }

  ...MORE LOGIC HERE...

    return transMD.recordNewTransaction(new Transaction(transID,transType,transNumOfShares,
        transPricePerShare,transTickerSymbol,transCommission,transComments));
}
```

When I make the POST, I get "java.lang.NumberFormatException: null" on `int transID = Integer.parseInt(newTransaction.get("id"));`

When I run the app in debug mode and do a POST, I can see that when `addTransaction()` method is reached, the `newTransaction` map is empty (hence the Null error above).
Why would the Map not be getting populated?

EDIT: My unit test, where I explicitly add to the Map, works:

```
@Test
public void makeNewTransaction() throws Exception{

    passedTransaction.put("id", "6");
    passedTransaction.put("type", "BUY");
    passedTransaction.put("numOfShares", "300");
    passedTransaction.put("pricePerShare", "37.23");
    passedTransaction.put("ticker", "XIV");
    passedTransaction.put("commission", "4.95");
    passedTransaction.put("comments","Testing Testing 1 2 3");

    Transaction newTrans = restCtrl.addTransaction(passedTransaction);
    assertEquals("XIV", newTrans.getSymbol());
}
```

Comment: `@PathVariable`? There are no path-variables in `"/transactions"`. Did you perhaps mean `@RequestBody` (or no argument annotation at all)?

Comment: Hot dog! Indeed Phil, that was the issues. What a silly mistake. Thanks.